# Desktop 'Padding'

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

Is there a way to add some padding to stop windows being completely full screen?
What I'm after is 20-30px of padding around my windows so that the background image shows when I make windows fullscreen rather than having to drag them to the size I want.

e.g.

[image: Fullscreen Desktop Padding]

Weird... I know.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have found (and currently use) uses the *Put* settings in CompizConfigSettingsManager.

I utilise the *Put Center* value, which puts the currently selected window to the center of the currently selected output (screen).

eg

Window off center:

[image: Off center window]

After hitting the *Put Center* hotkey:

[image: Example Put Center]

The steps to achieve this:

1. Install CCSM

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
   ```

   **TAKE CARE USING CCSM -** Brash use can cause problems with your Unity, only change settings explicitly shown, or that you know have no problems.
2. Search for and select *Put* in CCSM

   [image: CCSM - Put]
3. Assign a unique keyboard shortcut for *Put Center* (I use ctrl+alt+kp5)

   [image: Enable Put]

   If you utilise the *Put Left/Right/etc* hotkeys, you will want to set the window padding value too.
4. Under the Misc. Options tab, increase the padding values to your desired values (my *Pad Top* value is less than the others because I use a transparent menu bar)

   [image: CCSM - Put - Misc. Options - Padding]
5. Enable *Put*

<strike>For my 14.04 installation, window sizes seem to be remembered - so if I open and close Firefox to a specific size, it stays that size for subsequent openings - all you will need to do is hit your *Put Center* hotkey, and the window will be positioned in the center of your screen. However</strike> CCSM also includes a setting to fix the size of your windows to a certain dimension. This can be used in unison with the *Put Top/Bottom/Left/Right/Center* hotkeys to achieve the window padding you're after.

With the window that you want to fix the size of open, open CCSM and search for the *Window Rules* setting. Change to the *Size rules* tab.

[image: CCSM - Window Rules - Size rules]

Click *New*, the + icon, followed by the *Grab* button. With the *Grab* button selected, you then move across and click anywhere on your desired window, and the name of that window should pop up in the *Value* text box. Click *Add* and then set the desired Width and Height of the window. This will lock the window to that size any time you open it. You can also stop the window from being able to be maximized by setting the appropriate tag in the *Matches* tab.

An example of using the *Put Top* and *Put Bottom* hotkeys can be shown in the following screenshot of one of my vertical monitors. Using the *Window Rules* setting I've set the size of my terminal window to be of a fixed size (you'll notice there is no *Maximize* button in the top left of the window). With the terminal windows size being fixed, I then put the top terminal using the *Put Top* hotkey and the bottom one using the *Put Bottom* hotkey.
<strike>If you want to see how to use this *Window Rules* setting for your certain windows, just let me know and I'll run you through that too.</strike>

[image: Example of Put Top & Put Bottom]

I think this is an example of the window padding that you're after.